# Edit Download Link on Woocommerce thank you page

Tags: wordpress, filter, woocommerce, action, webhooks

I'm trying to work out how to edit the download button link that sits directly underneath the order title, in the order details section of the thank you page.

So if you make an order in Woocommerce, for a product that is downloadable, you get a "**Thank you. Your order has been received**" box, then under it, you get an "**Order Details**" box.

In that order details box, it shows each product ordered, and if that product is downloadable, it shows a small "**Download: Product name**" link under the product title.

I want to *hook/filter* into that download link, and edit it ( changing the text mainly, but also restyling it).

I've tried finding the action that adds it, but can't seem to work out where it's based, and then how to filter into it to change it's appearance.  I did also try to add a function that include a different download link using `woocommerce_order_item_meta_end`, then hide the old link, but can't work out how to get the product download link URL either.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any filters to do that so you'd need to copy the `\templates\order\order-downloads.php` template file into your child theme folder and make modifications to the following line in that file.

```
case 'download-file':
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $download['download_url'] ) . '" class="woocommerce-MyAccount-downloads-file button alt">' . esc_html( $download['download_name'] ) . '</a>';
    break;
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be in the MyAccount page, I'm looking to edit the link in the Thank You page that appears directly after an order.

Comment: It's the same template, it's used on the My Account page and Order Received endpoint.

Comment: I don't think it is.  That echo includes a class of "woocommerce-MyAccount-downloads-file" whereas my thank you page doesn't.

Comment: It has a class of "download-url" within a <small> tag

Comment: It depends if your theme has already modified these templates or not.  With the stock WooCommerce templates the download link is modified by the template I specified.

Comment: I'm using Avada - just checked the template files in the main theme though and that one isn't in there at all :/  Tried adding that theme file to the child theme also and it doesn't make any difference to the thank you page.

Comment: It's possible to override WooCommerce templates via plugins, that would be next check, look at what your plugins are doing.

Comment: What directory did you add the WooCommerce template in the child theme?

Comment: I'm a pretty experienced WP dev, so I don't think it's something that simple.  I did a search through the WooCommerce plugin and found that the link is in a legacy file in the woocommerce plugin... not sure it's got a hook.

Comment: Alternative option is to hide the download-url class completely, and add a new download link to the woocommerce_order_item_meta_end - but I can't work out how to get the download URL of the product in the thank you page.

Comment: Modifying the template is the easiest option.  Test it out on a default WordPress theme with no plugins and you'll see that editing the template updates the Thank You and My Account download links.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  In this instance modifying the template isn't the easiest option for me.  The easiest option is to hide the old download button via it's CSS class, and insert a whole new link into the woocommerce_order_item_meta_end hook with a function. The client is adamant that the change should be done via functions.php.  Any ideas on how to get the URL of the product download?

Comment: Yes, you can loop over all the cart item via WC()->cart->get_cart(); and then from checking the product class I think you can get the download link from the function get_downloads().