# Woocommerce downloadable product link to external Folder and not file download

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, download, product, digital

I want to user WooCommerce to offer digital products. Now I want the Download-Link to work as a redirection link. The product download link should call another platform and is not a file.

Process:

- Someone buys a digital product in the online shop
- There is a download link on the "Thank you" page, that will redirect the user to another platform and will not start a file download
- As confirmation E-Mail the customer will receive also the external platform link

Any kind solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use an external link as download link, but be careful, these redirect links are not safe out of the box (meaning anyone with the link can access it): [WooCommerce add downloadable product from external source](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-add-downloadable-product-from-external-source/)

If you need to make any other changes:
Copy the \templates\order\order-downloads.php template file into your child theme folder and change this code snippet:

```
case 'download-file':
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $download['download_url'] ) . '" class="woocommerce-MyAccount-downloads-file button alt">' . esc_html( $download['download_name'] ) . '</a>';
    break;
```

Credits: [Edit Download Link on Woocommerce thank you page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48867791/edit-download-link-on-woocommerce-thank-you-page)